# When many users uses a same webpage, will functionality in that webpage may behave abnormally?

Tags: html, .net, iis, server, visual-studio-2003

I have a website where it was hosted in 10 servers. From past somedays many users a using a particular webpage. so some functionalities in that particular webpage are not working as expected. They are behaving abnormally

For Example : I have a clear button on the page where user clicks on the button and it should clear all the checkboxes. But it was not clearing all the checkboxes. It was not a code error because we are using this webpage from many years.

More Details :
*It is a Vb.Net code
*.Net 1.1 version
*VS2003
*We have hosted code in 10 servers, where if a server has heavy load it changes to other(Load Balancer).
*Windows 2008R2
*IIS Version 7.5.7600.16385

My question is "As many users are using the webpage frequently will there be any thing happening" or any other reasons or bugs why this is happening. Any theoretical explanation for this issue please?

Comment: Unfortunately we saw many claims similar to "It was not a code error because we are using this webpage from many years" but finally the causes were simply in the source code of the web apps which only reveal themselves when the applications took high load (much more than they were originally designed to handle). So to get started on troubleshooting, ask some senior engineers to profile the application under load testing. "I have tried it in my dev machine" is usually not helpful, because a dev machine (like Windows 10/11) can never take much load.

Answer (score 1):

I could see that you are using VS 2003, VB.Net 1.1, Windows Server 2008 R2, and IIS 7.5 All the products you are using are out of support now.

Generally when many users use the web page then also it should work properly without any issues. As your project type is too old, it is difficult for us to comment on the possible cause of the issue.

One thing you could check is whether the website works fine on any of the 10 servers. If yes, compare the Server configuration and app settings with the Server that is having the issue.

See whether any Windows update got installed or if any configuration or code change occurred. It might give you some hints.

Check the browser console for errors. If you have the project then try to run it on your development machine to check whether it works. It could be possible, that some things got changed and you need to update your code according to it.

Comment: I got to know that this same thing happened 2 years ago, so considering this as 2nd time. I have tried it in my dev machine. It is working fine. But in qut and production it is not working. 
I can see there is only diff in the authentication in IIS. 
It will help me if you can list what configurations should i compare.

Comment: ASP.NET 1.1 is known to have too many performance issues which Microsoft addressed in .NET Framework 2.x/4.x. Merely upgrading to .NET Framework 4.8 should significantly improve on both performance and security sides. However, I don't think Windows updates are irrelevant here. Besides, ASP.NET 1.1 does not have much browser side code and most of the logic is executed on server side, so browser console won't help much (compared to modern web apps written primarily in JavaScript/TypeScript).